# Try and Except FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am setting up a program to use a specified file location but want to be able to change it if the file gets moved. I want the program to read the notepad file which contains the link to the correct file location. As you can see, the try and except is not working as I would like it to and can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
def hours():

    #getting username
    global username
    username = getpass.getuser() 

    #defining excel location
    try:
        global filelocation
        filelocation = r'\\flash\Users\Coop\Volunteering\ProgramReferenceX.xlsx'
    except FileNotFoundError:
        global desktop
        desktop = r'C:\Users\\' + username + '\Desktop\Filelocation.txt'
        filelocationtext = open(desktop,'r')
        filelocation = filelocationtext.read()


    global filelog
    filelog=pd.read_excel(filelocation ,read_only=True, sheetname=None, na_filter=False)


    #setting password
    global passwordx

    logbook=pxl.load_workbook(filelocation, data_only=False)
    ashx=logbook['datasheet']

    passwordx = ashx.cell(row=16, column=15).value
```

What I get as an output is:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '\\flash\Users\Coop\Volunteering\ProgramReferenceX.xlsx'

Comment: in`try` you are just declaring the filename which is just a string and not actually dealing with the file which you are doing in the except block. Still your question needs some more clarification

Comment: Please add to the question that part of you code which you're using `filelocation` variable name for the first time right after defining it.

Comment: There is *no way* the code you posted can produce that exception.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd I updated my code

Comment: Here the exception is thrown `pd.read_excel(filelocation)` which is outside of try block. Move that piece in try block and then exception should be handled as expected

Comment: @mad_ Would that still allow it to change file locations since it would be before the exception which could change the file location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FileNotFoundError` will not be raised when doing string assignment. So,

```
global filelocation
filelocation = r'\\flash\Users\Coop\Volunteering\ProgramReferenceX.xlsx'
```

will *never* throw a `FileNotFoundError`. The exception may occur, though, when you are *opening* a file, like you're doing here:

```
filelocationtext = open(desktop,'r')
```

You need to put the call to `open` in the `try` block, and act accordingly if the error is thrown.

Btw, I don't think the stack trace you gave can happen when you run your posted code. But either way, you want the call to `open` in the `try` block: not the `except` block.

**EDIT (since code's been updated):**

`pd.read_excel` also opens a file (and `px.load_workbook` probably does too). It can throw a `FileNotFoundError` as well. You'll want to put it in the `try` block and act accordingly if the file can't be found. This is probably what generated the posted stack trace since the filename your OS can't find is given by the `filelocation` variable.